# Get JWT token from Appsync Resolver Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-appsync

I am using **oidc** as authentication in AWS Appsync. For some purpose I need the **base64encoded** version of **JWT TOken** in the **resolver mapping template**. Can anyone suggest any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way here:

```
#set($token = $context.request.headers.get("authorization"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Custom Headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html) for this.

With custom headers you can pass in additional information into your request and access in your mapping templates.

Your mapping template could contain a line like:

```
#set($encodedToken = $utils.toJson($context.request.headers.encodedToken))
```

Doing this would allow you format the data as needed on the client before making the request.